# "error retrieving resource lock i/o timeout" kubebuilder k8s controller deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I'm trying to deploy a custom controller built using kubebuilder to my local k8s cluster. I have installed this k8s cluster from Docker Desktop settings.

Now, everything is working as expected when I ran it using "make run" on my machine. As it is working fine, I've ran the command "make docker-build custom-controller:0.1.0" and then ran the "make deploy custom-controller:0.1.0"

This worked fine, it has created a seperate namespace and this controller is running as a pod in that namespace and when I see the logs, I'm getting the following errors

```
2024-03-26T13:49:16Z    INFO    setup   starting manager
2024-03-26T13:49:16Z    INFO    starting server {"kind": "health probe", "addr": "[::]:8081"}
2024-03-26T13:49:16Z    INFO    controller-runtime.metrics  Starting metrics server
2024-03-26T13:49:16Z    INFO    controller-runtime.metrics  Serving metrics server  {"bindAddress": "127.0.0.1:8080", "secure": false}
I0326 13:49:16.092772       1 leaderelection.go:250] attempting to acquire leader lease vault-system/9737ddd2.ivzdso...
E0326 13:49:46.093895       1 leaderelection.go:332] error retrieving resource lock vault-system/9737ddd2.ivzdso: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/vault-system/leases/9737ddd2.ivzdso": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0326 13:50:18.973156       1 leaderelection.go:332] error retrieving resource lock vault-system/9737ddd2.ivzdso: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/vault-system/leases/9737ddd2.ivzdso": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

The ip [10.96.0.1](https://10.96.0.1) is the cluster-ip

kubernetes  ClusterIP  10.96.0.1  443/TCP  4d21h

What is the reason behind this? Is it some issue with the k8s controller or the cluster itself. And is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article by [Dipesh Shah](https://sdipesh.medium.com/nginx-ingress-error-retrieving-resource-lock-ingress-pods-missing-load-balancer-ip-addresses-e3938884ef8d) with the same error encountered. As per the article it might be a permission issue with the service account for ingress controller while acquiring leases.

They extracted the clusterrole yaml with

`kubectl get clusterrole -n ingress-nginx`

`kubectl get clusterrole nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx -o yaml`

Once extracted, the yaml clusterrole lists down all the rules associated with different apiGroups, however you should keep a close eye with "coordination.k8s.io"

They updated their clusterrole yaml with the command and added the rule for "coordination.k8s.io" apiGroup

`kubectl edit clusterrole nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx -o yaml`

Code snippet added:

-apiGroups:

— coordination.k8s.io

resources:

— leases

verbs:

— create

— get

— list

— update

You may consider checking the API server address, typically kubebuilder controllers use in-cluster configuration to discover the API server address automatically. Verify if there's any explicit configuration overriding the default behavior.

Comment: coredns pods in my k8s cluster were crashing, I tried changing the forward proxy in configmap but it didn't help, may this is due to my corporate network proxy.